# In firebase, is it possible to make query at 2nd level node, without knowing the value of 1st node?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please see the attached image, as I only know the value of the 2nd node(`-M5Cc-PcLR9HfRQyJ0SU`), is it possible to make query base on this and get the value of the 1st node (`-M5ukIV79GHeUc0FnVUI`)?

Thank you.

[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5LCl.png)

Comment: Is `DEVPCD` the name of a document or the name of a collection?

Comment: Actually it is Firebase Realtime Database, so DEVPCD is name of a node.

Comment: If we take the question literally, you don't need a query and the answer is yes, you can get to that data based on the information provided. Again though, it will NOT be a query - you would read the top level node *-M5Cc-Pc...* and then read the first node within that snapshot. That will give you the *-M5Cc9t* node which contains *Item 01*. Again, you're asking for the 1st node and that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  You need to be able to build the full path of node to query.  There are no wildcards.

You migth want to consider duplicating the data in such a way that you can find it without the parent node.  This sort of data duplication is common in nosql type databases.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the question literally, you don't need a query and the answer is yes, you can get to that data based on the information provided.

Again though, it will NOT be a query.

You asked:

> get the value of the 1st node

To get the **first node** within the *-M5Cc9t* node, you would read the top level node -M5Cc-Pc... and then read the first node within that snapshot.

That will give you the -M5Cc9t node which contains Item 01. Again, you're asking for the 1st node and that will do it.

Here's the code based on your stucture (I abbreviated the node names)

```
func readChildNode() {
    let nodeRefWeKnow = self.ref.child("DEVPCD").child("-M5uklV").child("-M5Cc-Pc")
    nodeRefWeKnow.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allSnapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        if let firstSnapshot = allSnapshots.first {
            let name = firstSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name")
            print(name)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
Snap (name) Item 01
```